# DataFrame - Append results and sum

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say i have a big amount of different DataFrames that may or may not have similar indexes.
here are 2 examples:

```
#1
fruit     count                          
Apple     3
Banana    1
Orange    4

#2
fruit     count                     
Apple     1
watermelon 5
```

I want to append every DataFrame to a 'Total' DataFrame that will looks like this:

```
fruit                          
Apple     4
Banana    1
Orange    4
Watermelon 5
```

How would you do that?

Comment: What did you try to do? I would first `pd.concat` the two DataFrames, and then `groupby` with `sum`.

Comment: `pd.concat((df1,df2)).groupby('fruit').sum()`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
all_dfs = [df1,df2,df3] # populate this list with all your dataframes
acc_df = all_dfs.pop()
for df in all_dfs:
    acc_df = acc_df.concat(df, ignore_index=True)
acc_df.groupby(['fruit'])["count"].sum()
```